# Get every indexOf in ArrayList using a String

Tags: c#, arraylist, indexof

First off I am using c# inside of unity. Okay, I have an ArrayList. List items we will call it. items contents are {apple, apple, berry, apple, nut}; I want to know of a way to find all the index numbers of apple using items.indexOf(); or some other function. The list of contents is just for example, in the program I am using I won't actually know the contents for sure as they will be varying lists in size and content. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't iterate through list items?

Comment: To get a good understanding refer to this http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-indexof

Comment: I should have clarified,... I don't necessarily know the contents of items... I'm using this to run an inventory,... this will be getting needed items to do things and will have to run through many different sets of needs with different contents... So I can't use a method that assumes I know the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non Linq way of doing it:

```
private static List<int> Find(ArrayList items, string entry)
{
    var ret = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        if ((string) items[i] == entry)
            ret.Add(i);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I was so caught up in using indexOf or some method like that I didn't even think about other ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var result = list
    .Cast<TypeOfTheObjects>()                       // non-generic ArrayList needs a cast
    .Select((item, index) => new { Index = index, Item = item }) // select each item with its index
    .Where(x => apple.Equals(x.Item))               // filter
    .Select(x => x.Index)                           // select only index
    .ToList();
```

Depending on the type of the objects (and their `Equals` implementation), you might have to modify the equality check.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = yourList.Cast<Fruit>()
                      .Select((fruit, index) => fruit.Name == "apple" ? index : -1)
                      .Where(elem => elem >= 0)
                      .ToList();
```